# How to change time zone in MYSQL database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table `myTable` in my `MYSQL database` in which there is a column called `INSERT_DATE` which is `datetime` type and having a default value of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

While making an insert statement, this column automatically picks the current time from my system.

This is working very well on my localhost. But when I hosted my website to a server placed somewhere else in some different timezone, its picking time from that time zone which is wrong. I want to set timezone to `GMT + 5:30` `('Asia/Kolkata')`. How can I achieve this in `MYSQL`?

I am trying to change timezone while connecting to database, but it is not working. Below is my code:

```
function connect_database()
{
    $con = mysqli_connect("servername", "username", "password", "dbname");
    if (!$con) 
    {
        $con = "";
        echo("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    mysqli_query($con, "SET SESSION time_zone = 'Asia/Kolkata'");
    return $con;
}
```

Comment: change the default time zone as 'Asia/Kolkata' in your cPanel.

Comment: @MathsRkBala - Do I need to raise a ticket to my hosting providers to change the time zone for my cpanel?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the beginning of your script, just after connection to MySQL, execute this query:

```
SET SESSION time_zone = 'Asia/Kolkata';
```

Documentation: [MySQL Server Time Zone Support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time-zone-support.html)

if you get an error when executing the query:

```
ERROR 1298 (HY000): Unknown or incorrect time zone: 'Asia/Kolkata'
```

then it means the timezone data is not loaded in your MySQL server. You may do so by following the explanations given in the chapter [Populating the Time Zone Tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/time-zone-support.html) or you may try using numerical values instead of named timezones:

```
SET SESSION time_zone = "+5:30";
```

Comment: I tried your solution but its not working. I have updated my question.

Comment: What is not working? What do you get exactly? I use the same code for my database and it works fine.

Comment: its still picking server time zone.

Comment: I suggest you change the PHP code to check for mysql errors after executing the query with `mysqli_query`: add `or die(mysqli_error($con))` at the end of the line.

Comment: I was putting timezone wrong. It worked with "+5:30". Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 4):

for session scope

```
set time_zone = "+5:30"
```

global scope

```
set global time_zone = "+5:30"
```

> If you change a global system variable, the value is remembered and
>   used for new connections until the server restarts. (To make a global
>   system variable setting permanent, you should set it in an option
>   file.) The change is visible to any client that accesses that global
>   variable. However, the change affects the corresponding session
>   variable only for clients that connect after the change. The global
>   variable change does not affect the session variable for any client
>   that is currently connected (not even that of the client that issues
>   the SET GLOBAL statement).